# how to make overlay on rotating image

Tags: html, css

I am still learning about styles and looking for a solution where:

1. there is an overlay with a gradient from light gray to light turquoise that appears over the image
2. the picture is increased by 20% (it does not climb out of the original dimensions) and rotates 30 degrees clockwise
3. the animation all happens smoothly over 300ms

So I made the image scale and rotate but the overlay is making me crazy.

```css
.zoom-effect-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-card img {
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease;
  transition: 300ms ease
}

.zoom-effect-container:hover .image-card img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-effect-container">
  <div class="image-card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pseudo element:

```
.image-card:before { ... }
```

Apply a CSS gradient to that element. I used a generator site to whip up this example. Really easy to pick whatever settings you want: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#e0e0e0+0,00faff+100&0+0,0.65+100

`z-index` will be needed at that point to keep the "layers" stacking in the correct order.

```css
.zoom-effect-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.zoom-effect-container:hover .image-card:before {
  /* this is the overlay */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 250, 255, 0.65) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 250, 255, 0.65) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 250, 255, 0.65) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00e0e0e0', endColorstr='#a600faff', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.image-card img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease;
  transition: 300ms ease;
}

.zoom-effect-container:hover .image-card img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2) rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-effect-container">
  <div class="image-card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. `:before` is a much more portable way of solving this! Also, thanks for the picsum auto-size image link; very useful for these type of snippets.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you want to do with the gradient overlay. For now, the example below:

- Adds a `div` for gradients inside the container, and overlays it on top of the image. Because we are using `position: absolute` for both and the gradient `div` comes after the image `div`, the gradient `div` goes on top of the image `div`. Otherwise, we'd have to use `z-index` to control which `div` goes on top.
- The overlay `div` sets `top, right, bottom, left` all to `0` to cover the full container.
- The overlay `div` uses `opacity` to let us see through it with the transparency effect. `.2` means 20% transparent. `0` is completely see-through; `1` is completely solid/opaque.
- Adds `:hover` on overlay `div` to show a `linear-gradient()` on the `background`.

```css
.zoom-effect-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.image-card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.image-card img {
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease;
  transition: 300ms ease;
}

.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: .2;
}

.zoom-effect-container:hover .image-card img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(30deg);
}

.zoom-effect-container:hover .gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgray, turquoise);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom-effect-container">
  <div class="image-card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Useful links to learn more:

- [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)
- [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)
- [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)